# How to upload image in to php server using Multipart

Tags: android, http-post, multipart

I have been headache , how to upload image in to server.It is new task for me.but big confusing for me.i searched on stackoverflow and googled. but i getting problems.

***My intention is Upload photo from sdcard and take photo from camera and upload to server.***

In ios, this task already done, in ios php get this type of: When posting php side simple hit this information.

and Print Like this;

```
$filedata = $_FILES['photos'];
$f = fopen(time().".txt",'wb');
fwrite($f, print_r($_REQUEST,true));
fclose($f);
```

---

```
   [photos] => Array
        (
            [name] => game.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpiQHIXQ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1664972
        )
```

What I do.

```
   // yourSelectedImage is the bitmap image.
    public void SaveImage() throws Exception {
            try {
                 String url = "http://test.com/uploadImage.php";
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
                
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg");
              
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                reqEntity.addPart("photos", bab);
            
                postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String sResponse;
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
     
                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    s = s.append(sResponse);
                }
                System.out.println("Response: " + s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle exception here
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

In Php Server, Getting  like this

**$filedata = $_FILES['photos'];**

and further function done in php.

But I am not posting  using httppost in to  the multipart above type of structure of file, where file includes image name, image type,temp name, and others.

**Edited:**

I have Change Little bit Code:, But failed to post image file information php server, userid ok but image file information could not post.In this case, Image save successfully on server, i could not get information on php sever of image.

Here is the Code:

public class UploadImageHttpPost {

```
String testpath="/mnt/sdcard/14111.jpg";
String url = "http://test.com/uploadImage.php";

public static void sendPost(String url, String imagePath,String userId)
        throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
    Log.w("TAG", "Start Upload" );
    Log.w("TAG", "URL-> "+url );
    Log.w("TAG", "Image Path-> "+imagePath );
    Log.w("TAG", "User Id-> "+userId );
    String responseBody;

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    File file = new File(imagePath);
    FileBody encFile = new FileBody(file,"image/jpeg");
    Log.w("TAG", "image file-> "+encFile );
    entity.addPart("photos", encFile);
    entity.addPart("UserId", new StringBody(userId));
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setEntity(entity);
    
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    ResponseHandler<String> responsehandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    responseBody = client.execute(request, responsehandler);

    if (responseBody != null && responseBody.length() > 0) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Response from image upload->" + responseBody);

    }
}
```

I get Like this:

```
Array
(
    [UserId] => 914
)
```

But here below part missing means i am not getting, is there any missing code in multipart post method please check above java code:

```
[photos] => Array
        (
            [name] => game.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpiQHIXQ
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1664972
        )
```

Would you please correct me, How to post on php, above information of image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
File file = new File(_filePath);
MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
multipart.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse res;
URI uri = new URI(url.php);


HttpPost methodpost = new HttpPost(uri);
methodpost.addHeader("pragma","no-cache");
methodpost.setEntity(multipart);
res = httpClient.execute(methodpost);

InputStream data = res.getEntity().getContent();
```

Sure, to complete with what you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Upload image using Multipart entity

```
    File file1 = null;
    FileBody bin1 = null;    

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

      // uri for your image path   
                   if(uri != null)
                   {   
                       file1 = new File(getPath(uri));

                       bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
                   }


           MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();



                   if(bin1!=null)
                       reqEntity.addPart("profile_image", bin1);


                   post.setEntity(reqEntity);


                     HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                     int mResponse_code =  httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


                     resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



                     response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

And Parse your json response. It is very simple way.