# Save an Image in app folder

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I'm new in Android development and I have an app that saves a 'jogador' (player) record with some attributes (name, birthday...) and a photo.

When the user picks the image from gallery, I populate an `ImageView` with the photo so that the user can see it before he saves the record. (It's working here).

My problem is that I want to save that photo in a folder created by me (Inside `res/` folder). eg: `res/myFolder`.

I don't know how I will access that folder to put an image inside. Follow my code bellow:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fotoPath); //---> It works
FileOutputStream fos;

try {

    // 'fotos_jogador' is my folder inside res folder.
    // I think that 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()' 
    // gives me access to sdcard, but i don't want this, I want to save in a local app folder. 

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                         File.separator + "/fotos_jogador/" + ".png");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    //I want do store a low quality image, just for contact photo.
    if(fos != null){
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 20, fos);  
        fos.close();
    }
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, guys, my doubts:

1. How can I give a custom name for my Image?
2. How can I Save the image in my folder 'fotos_jogador'?
3. How can I retrieve the Image after it's saved?

I appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: May be help this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506594/not-posting-image-file-in-android-using-multipart-httppost-method/16529053#16529053

Comment: Search your external storage for the hidden file `".png"`!!

Comment: You can't because the /res folder is situated inside the apk file and can't be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you can not save anything in resource folder here is the link of duplicate post [Is it possible to save image in assets folder from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788519/is-it-possible-to-save-image-in-assets-folder-from-application) 
you can save image in sd card or in internal memory.

Comment: Right. What's the best way to do it? Can you help me? Thanks a lot!